# Why did Avraham take gifts from Pharaoh, but not the King of Sodom?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, avot-patriarch-fathers, gifts, parashat-lech-lecha

In [Bereshit 12:11-16](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0112.htm#11), we see that Avraham was willing to receive gifts from Pharoah:

> 11 And it came to pass, when he was come near to enter into Egypt, that he said unto Sarai his wife: 'Behold now, I know that thou art a fair woman to look upon.
>
> 12 And it will come to pass, when the Egyptians shall see thee, that they will say: This is his wife; and they will kill me, but thee they will keep alive.
>
> 13 Say, I pray thee, thou art my sister; that it may be well with me for thy sake **(They will give me gifts. - [Rashi](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8176/showrashi/true#v13))**, and that my soul may live because of thee.'
>
> 14 And it came to pass, that, when Abram was come into Egypt, the Egyptians beheld the woman that she was very fair.
>
> 15 And the princes of Pharaoh saw her, and praised her to Pharaoh; and the woman was taken into Pharaoh's house.
>
> 16 And he dealt well with Abram for her sake; and he had sheep, and oxen, and he-asses, and men-servants, and maid-servants, and she-asses, and camels.

Yet he refused gifts from the King of Sodom ([Bereshit 14:21-24](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0114.htm#21)):

> 21 And the king of Sodom said unto Abram: 'Give me the persons, and take the goods to thyself.'
>
> 22 And Abram said to the king of Sodom: 'I have lifted up my hand unto the LORD, God Most High, Maker of heaven and earth,
>
> 23 that I will not take a thread nor a shoe-latchet nor aught that is thine, lest thou shouldest say: I have made Abram rich;
>
> 24 save only that which the young men have eaten, and the portion of the men which went with me, Aner, Eshcol, and Mamre, let them take their portion.'

[Rashi 14:23](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8209/showrashi/true#v23) explains why Avraham didn't want to take anything from the king of Sodom:

> **that you should not say, [I have made Abram rich]**: The Holy One, blessed be He, promised to make me rich, as it is said (above 12:2): “and I will bless you, etc.”

Why wasn't he worried Pharaoh would say the same thing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I heard in the name of the *Maharal* (in *Gur Arye*, but I haven't had a chance to check it inside,) that *Avram* understood that the wealth *Hashem* had promised him would come through natural means, and that he therefore didn't mind taking gifts from people. But *Bera*'s gifts were awarded to him for distasteful acts, so he understood that those could not be the means *Hashem* intended for him to gain wealth. So he declined them: if those are not the fulfillment of the *Hashem*'s promise, then he didn't want to take them. (This fits in with *Rashi* (as one might expect of the *Gur Arye*): *Rashi* says he had *Hashem*'s promise in mind when he refused *Bera*'s gifts.)

---

My kid answered that *Avram* didn't want *Bera* to say he had enriched him, but there was little fear of that from *Par'o* who, being distant, would not hear if *Avram* became rich [rather than, perhaps, losing his money to bandits on the way home].

And I heard in the name of an irreligious Jew that *Avram* was unwilling to accept gifts as recompense for doing kindness so as to increase *kidush Hashem*, whereas that concern was irrelevant in *Mitzrayim*. (This does *not* easily fit in with *Rashi*, who says he didn't want to accept from *Bera* because of *Hashem*'s promise.)

Comment: Re what I heard in the name of an irreligious Jew, see also [another answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11128) and comments thereto.

Comment: Here's the Gur Aryeh:: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14210&pgnum=90

Comment: Here's a loose translation of the Gur Aryeh: ------ The King of Sodom only gave Avraham the money because he was captured and the loss he incurred. Avraham realized that this money wasn't part of the blessing of wealth G-d gave him, since 
"Blessing"  is not something that comes from distress. Pharaoh on the other hand, gave Avraham wealth in order to honor him. This is the blessing G-d gave Avraham, that he would be honored by others until the give him gifts...

Comment: ...[Although Pharaoh gave him presents because of the plague that befell him (so I might think this is also a gift that came from distress), Pharaoh's gift was considered a blessing because it was part of his atonement. This was not the case with the King of Sodom]

Comment: ---- This is slightly different than the answer given above, since the distinction is not whether the money came through natural means or not, but whether the gifts were given out of distress or from a place of good.

Comment: irreligious or nonobservant?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, Wiktionary has [_religious_](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/religious) meaning "committed to the practice of religion" and [_observant_](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/observant) meaning "diligently attentive in observing a law, custom, duty or principle": are those different, when referring to Judaism in toto? In any event, I don't recall now in whose name I heard it (or from whom), so will have to trust what I wrote when I penned this answer.

Comment: @msh210 I apologize for being so picky on such and old post.  But I would say this: Observance has to do with observance of halakha.  Religiosity has to do with participation in religion.  There are many non-observant Reform Jews (and a few observant ones but that's unrelated).

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, participation in Judaism is (or at the very least includes as a major component) observance of _halacha_.

Answer (score 11):

The body of your question differs slightly from the title, so I will focus on that (i.e. why he wasn't worried Pharoah would say the same thing). Here's an answer from [this Ohr Somayach Parsha Q&A](http://ohr.edu/qa/5761/bereishi/lech.htm) (see Kasha section), as heard from Rabbi Michael Bachar:

> Avraham suspected that the king of Sodom would publicize the fact that he enriched Avraham. Pharaoh, on the other hand, wouldn't brag about his gifts to Avraham. Since they were given under embarrassing circumstances, Pharaoh would avoid mentioning them in order to avoid drawing attention to the incident.

You can also see there for a different answer on the question in your title...

Comment: Why do you feel the Abarbanel's answer wouldn't work according to Rashi?

Comment: In case that link goes down, I'll copy here from there the "different answer" (quoted there in the name of _Abarbanel_) that this post alludes to: Had _Avram_ refused _Par'o_'s gift, _Par'o_ might have realized they were married.

Answer (score 7):

The book *Hege Yona* (Jerusalem 5756), by my grandfather-in-law Rabbi *Yona* Munk, includes the following (in my own free translation):

> 14:23: "or if I take anything from you, lest you say 'I enriched *Avram*'"
>
> The question that arises is why *Avraham* agreed to take gifts from *Par'o* and *Avimelech*, not worrying they'd say they enriched *Avram*.
>
> One can simply differentiate: He had no choice but to take from *Par'o* and *Avimelech*, as they were rulers over the land he was in, and not accepting their gifts would slight them, which could be dangerous to him. The king of *S'dom* was different: *Avram* had just saved his life, and he was completely poor.
>
> But truly, he accepted *Par'o* and *Avimelech*'s gifts willingly, as he knew this was from *Hashem*, a fulfillment of "*vaavarech'cha*" (as *Rashi* explains, with money). But one can infer from the following verse, "*vaavar'cha m'var'checha*", where *Hashem*'s blessing is written before that of the person who blesses *Avraham* (as opposed to "*umkalelcha aor*", where *Hashem*'s curse is written after the people's), that the blessing of *Hashem* will have already reached those who try to benefit *Avram*. That is, they will benefit him when already rich. So it didn't make sense that "*vaavar'cha m'var'checha*" would be talking about a gift from someone lowly like the king of *S'dom*.
>
> And one can make an additional distinction. *Par'o* and *Avimelech*, whose punishment came through a revelation of *Hashem* to them (*Par'o* knew the punishment he was getting was for *Saray*), understood that *Hashem* wanted to protect *Avraham* and *Sara*, so gave them gifts to enrich them, as an appeasement of *Hashem*. Therefore, *Avraham* didn't worry they'd say "I enriched *Avraham*". The king of *S'dom*, on the other hand, had no angel appear to him, and he only made his offer of riches to *Avram* after he saw that *Avram* had given *maaser* to *Malki Tzedek*. His offer "*v'es har'chush kach lach*" implies that he considered the wealth his own, and that he was giving it to *Avram* (otherwise, he could just say "*ten li hanefesh*") — but really it was *Avram*'s and his men's, as spoils of war. This gall of the king of *S'dom*, especially that he said this after *Avram* tithed, as if to say "don't tithe until it's yours", is what angered *Avram*. So he answered "*v'im ekach mikol asher **lach** v'al tomar ani heesharti es Avram*". Meaning, "from someone like you, who maintains that the wealth is his own, as you've just insisted on publicly, I can't accept, as you'll say 'I enriched *Avram*'. I will be enriched by *Hashem*, in a way that everyone will know that he did it".

If I understand his last explanation correctly, he means to distinguish the *S'dom* case from the others by saying that *Bera* would not acknowledge that *Avram*'s wealth would come from *Hashem*, so would say "I enriched *Avram*", whereas the other kings would acknowledge *Avram*'s wealth would come from *Hashem*. How did *Avram* know this? By the facts that (1) *Bera* was so audacious as to incorrectly insist the wealth was his own, and (2) the other kings were appeasing *Hashem* by offering the gifts.

Answer (score 5):

Isn't it simply that Avraham had not yet received the promises of land and dynasty when he was in Egypt but he had by the time he was in S'dom? The last thing that happened before he went to rescue Lot was that dual promise. Following that, Avraham resolved to receive the good things that were coming to him from Hashem alone.

Comment: How do you figure? According to the view that the bris bein habesarim took place when Avraham was 70, then that preceded both the encounter with Pharaoh and the war with the four kings. If we go with the order as given in the Torah, then the BBHB is recorded after both of them.

Comment: @Alex: WAF may be referring to Bereshit 13:14-17 - http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8208/showrashi/true/jewish/Chapter-13.htm#v14 , although that was not a covenant.

Comment: @Alex and Menachem, you are both right. Thank you for the correction and _limud z'chus_. I have edited my answer. But over _shabas_ it also occurred to me (although I didn't see it inside) that maybe _S'dom_ was just more reprehensible than _Mitzrayim_ so Avraham wanted no association with it, as he says.

Answer (score 4):

Rav Shlomo Kluger in his sefer Imrei Shefer [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38352&st=&pgnum=15) explains that the posuk in [Proverbs 15:27](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16386#v=27) does not say that 
"one who **does not accept** gifts will live", but "one who **hates** gifts will live",
because sometimes it is necessary to accept gifts even though he hates them, for example, 
to pay off debts which is a mitzvah.

Therefore, he continues, Avrohom accepted the gifts from the Egyptians because he needed to pay off his debts after he left Egypt, 
as Rashi explains [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8208#showrashi=true&v=3), but since he had
no debts after the war with the kings he refused to accept any gifts for himself from the king of Sodom.

Answer (score 3):

Someone e-mailed me:

> I was also thinking that from Pharaoh he took because it was to compensate for the suffering of Sara Imainu. Furthermore, "ain bracha metzuya b'baiso shel adam ela bishvil ishto", so he knew that was from the bracha, and the money from Sedom was not from the bracha.
>
> I think the tzu shtel of "ain bracha..." I heard from R' Helman in the Mir.

[*Tzu-shtel*, Yiddish, literally "stand-to", here roughly "connection". The maxim is from [*Bava M'tzia* 59:1](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3142&size=1).]

Answer (score 2):

This is an idea I heard some time ago.

Hashem promised Avraham that he will be wealthy.

Avraham knew that money that was given to him happily by the giver would be coming from 
Hashem. This is the case of Pharoah who gave the money willfully as presents.

In the case of S'dom the money actually belonged to Avraham: During the war S'dom lost it and Avraham go it back similar to the case of "Hefker". But he knew that the people of S'dom got nothing left and were very sad to have to depart from their belongings. This is how he knew that he should take this money.

The Torah Temima brings two additional ideas why not to keep S'dom's money:

1. Kidush Hashem: Avraham is giving money from a "metzia" which was his.
2. He knew that his victory was a miracle. In Masechet Ta'anit (24a) we learn you are not supposed to enjoy the fruits of a miracle.

Answer (score 2):

[*Hak'sav V'hakabala*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14121&pgnum=79) answers that *Avram* did not, in fact, receive gifts from *Par'o*. [The verse](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%91_%D7%98%D7%96) says only that *Par'o* did good to *Avram* and *Avram* had possessions, but does not say *Par'o* gave him anything: this means only that *Par'o* very kindly did not take any of *Avram*'s possessions away from him.

Note that this answer does not accord with [the *Rashi* quoted in the question](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8176/showrashi/true#v13), which said that *Avram* anticipated accepting gifts from *Par'o*. It also does not seem to address the *Avimelech* issue.

Answer (score 1):

[*Daas Sof'rim*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39781&pgnum=140) says the following (in my own free translation), but I don't pretend to understand it:

> "lest you say 'I enriched *Avram*'": It seems this was not the main reason for his refusal to take from the loot: after all, he did take gifts from *Par'o*. It was an additional reason directed at this wicked king, for *Avraham* knew he would pride himself on this.

(See also the comments on this post.)

Comment: Perviously, The Daas Sof'rim says that the reason Avraham didn't want to take the money was because Redeaming Captives is a mitzvah, and he didn't want to take money for doing a mitzvah. -http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39781&pgnum=138 . So what he told the King of Sodom was just an added reason/excuse.

Comment: @Menachem, ah, thank you! In that case, this is much like what [the irreligious Jew I quote in another answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11124) said.

Comment: very similar, but I think the Daas Sof'rim's focus is on the distastefulness of taking monetary reward for doing a mitzvah, as opposed to the kiddush hashem aspect of it.

Comment: I agree, @Menachem.

Answer (score 1):

The [Kli Yakar on 12:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Kli_Yakar_on_Genesis.12.9.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) gives another answer he focuses more on the gifts that all the Egyptians gave Avraham, as opposed to the gifts Pharaoh gave Avraham:

> הלוך ונסוע הנגבה. אולי רצה להתחכם באלהיות, כי הרוצה שיחכים ידרים (ב״ב כה:) אבל על העושר לא בקש, שהרי אמר אם אקח מחוט ועד שרוך נעל. ו**אותן מתנות שקיבל ע״י שרה היה מוכרח לקבלם כדי שלא יהרגוהו**, שהרי כולם נתנו לו דרך חנופה אולי יתפתה ליתן לו את אחותו לאשה, ואילו לא היה מקבל היו חושבים שאין רצונו ליתנה להם והיו הורגים אותו, ומ״מ לא רצה ליהנות מן אותן מתנות ונתנם לבני הפלגשים, שנאמר (בראשית כה ו) ולבני הפלגשים נתן אברהם מתנות. היינו אותן מתנות שכבר קבל מן המצריים נתנם לבני הפלגשים דהיינו בני קטורה והיא הגר המצרית כפירש״י, כי מן המצריים לקח המתנות והחזירם למתנתם ונתנם לבני הגר המצרית.

In short, Avraham was forced to accept the gifts he received from the Egyptians, in order to keep up the ruse that Sarah was his sister (since they were giving him gifts in order to try and convince him to let them marry his sister). Avraham did not want to benefit from the money, so he gave it all away to the sons of Keturah (Hagar, who was Egyptian) before he sent them away.